# Black screen and freeze within a minute of boot

Tags: release-freya, crash

I have installed elementary freya on it's own partition so that I can dual boot it with Windows 10. Within a minute of booting, the screen will go black, return to normal and then freeze. ctrl+alt+F1 does nothing. The mouse still moves but it's staggered and I can't click anything.

I assume this is a driver issue as I have elementary running fine on my laptop. My specs are:

- i5 4690k
- R9 390 8GB
- 8GB RAM

Any solutions or even a way to see an error message would be useful!